# Block Erupters Continue to err out

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-setup, bfgminer, error

Does anyone else have this problem?  I have to restart that computer and mining rig about once a day.  More than half will err out over 12 hours.  They can't recover by themselves?

O.S.: Ubuntu Server 12.04
mining program: bfgminer 3.3.0

```
$tmux
$sudo ~/bfgminer/bfgminer -o stratum+tcp://stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 -u MYWORKER -p MYPASS -S all
```

ctrl-B, ctrl-D
close terminal session

Nothing else is plugged into a USB port.  It's one of the simplest setups I can think to make.
Block erupters are less than a month old.  Block erupters have all the current they'd want at 5V (external power supply and their current demand doesn't get anywhere near the limit of the p.s.)

I'll try to come back as soon as I can find any specific error messages.

Should I not keep the mining executable in my home directory?

Comment: Most problems with block erupters is because they don't get enough power. Most hubs (even powered ones) and laptop usb ports are complete garbage and deliver below spec power.

Which USB hub is this on, and with which power supply?

Comment: this usb hub: http://www.amazon.com/10-Port-USB-2-0-Hub/dp/B00475WJEY/ref=sr_1_22?ie=UTF8&qid=1384479175&sr=8-22&keywords=usb+hub

Comment: powered with an external power supply that should be able to deliver up to 12A @5V

Comment: I've gotten this error occassionally: ./bfgminer: error while loading shared libraries: libblkmaker_jansson-0.1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: OK, so I found this thread: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=168174.140.  Re-cloning, configuring, makeing, and not moving directories around.  We'll see if the problem persists.

Comment: Problem persists! I found all my block erupters in the external hub erred out this morning.  Is it cooling?  The room they're in is pretty cool (windows was open and frosty outside) and exaust of power supply is on them, but I don't have a fan on them.  This is the error line: ICA 0:       | OFF  /244.3/234.5Mh/s | A:  657 R: 3+0(.45%) HW: 16/.83%